# SQL query to find whether all sub-parts exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table (Course) that has a one-to-many relationship with another table (SessionAttendance). I need to know whether *all* of the *many* records exist.

Part of the problem is I'm not sure how to explain the issue well, so it's hard to search :)

### Example

Here's a simplified example of what I'm trying to do. I found a (sub-optimal?) way to figure out if *one student* attended all session. But, not sure how to expand that to a general search

#### Scenario

A Course has multiple sessions. Attendance records who was present for a given session.

For each student and course, were all classes were attended, and what is the date of the last class taken?

#### One student

Here's when I came up with for a single student. Don't know of any aggregate that would return *NULL* when any *NULL* fields exist, so I ended up nesting CASE statements :-/ (Doesn't seem to hurt performance)

```
SELECT
    Course.Id,
    MAX(SessionAttendance.TakenOn) as TakenOn,
    CASE
        WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN SessionAttendance.Id is null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 THEN 0
        ELSE 1
    END as AttendedAllSessions    -- Is there a better way?
FROM Course
LEFT JOIN SessionAttendance
    ON Course.Id = SessionAttendance.CourseId
WHERE SessionAttendance.StudentId = 42
GROUP BY Course.Id
```

#### All students

This is where I'm not sure how to move forward. The *StudentId* only exists in the *Attendance* table. Can't add it to the *GROUP BY*, because the *NULLs* (from the LEFT JOIN) would all end up together

```
SELECT
    SessionAttendance.StudentId, -- NOPE: all NULL Attendance gets combined
    Course.Id,
    MAX(SessionAttendance.TakenOn) as TakenOn,
    CASE
        WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN SessionAttendance.Id is null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 THEN 0
        ELSE 1
    END as AttendedAllSessions
FROM Course
LEFT JOIN SessionAttendance
    ON Course.Id = SessionAttendance.CourseId
GROUP BY SessionAttendance.StudentId, Course.Id
```

#### Table definitions

```
CREATE TABLE Course (
    Id INT IDENTITY,
    Name VARCHAR(64)
);

CREATE TABLE SessionAttendance (
    Id INT IDENTITY,
    CourseId INT,   -- FK to Course.Id
    StudentId INT,  -- FK to Student.Id
    TakenOn DATETIME
);

CREATE TABLE Student (
    Id INT IDENTITY,
    Name VARCHAR(64)
);
```

Comment: Can you post your schema, so we don't have to guess from your queries?

Comment: done. Added some CREATE TABLE statements with datatype (fudged the FKs)

Comment: also renamed Attendance to SessionAttendance… to try and make it clearer that a Course has multiple sessions

Comment: Hmm, now I'm not sure my answer is correct. How do you know how many sessions there are in a course? Don't you need a Session table?

Comment: that's where my example kind of falls down :) in this case, we know there was a session because we have SessionAttendance records for that date

Comment: So if nobody turned up, there was no session? Deep :P I'll fix my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about if you just compare the count of attendance records to the total of course sessions available:

```
SELECT
    StudentId,
    CourseId,
    MAX(TakenOn) as TakenOn,
    case when Count(CourseId) = 
            (select COUNT(distinct TakenOn) 
            FROM SessionAttendance SessionAttendanceCount
            where SessionAttendanceCount.CourseId = SessionAttendance.CourseId
            ) then
        1
    else
        0
    end AttendedAllSessions
FROM SessionAttendance
GROUP BY StudentId, CourseId
```

Comment: nice. in my actual setup, "SessionAttendance" is the result of another query… and getting counts would only involve a couple hundred records (so it would be very fast)

Comment: I didn't realize that the "SessionAttendance" had multuple records for each course and student.  I updated the answer.

Comment: I ended up JOINing the counts instead of using subquery

Answer (score 1):

This query:

```
select 
    c.Id as CourseId, c.Name as CourseName, cs.SessionDate, 
    s.Id as StudentId, s.Name as StudentName, 
    case when a.Id is null then 0 else 1 end as Attended
from (
    select distinct CourseId, TakenOn [SessionDate] from SessionAttendance 
) cs
join Course c on c.Id=cs.CourseId
cross join Student s
left join SessionAttendance a 
    on a.CourseId=cs.CourseId and a.StudentId=s.Id and a.TakenOn=cs.SessionDate
order by c.Id, s.Id, cs.SessionDate
```

Gets you a list of all sessions in all courses combined with all students, and a flag showing whether each student attended each session:

```
CourseId    CourseName  SessionDate                 StudentId   StudentName Attended
1           CS101       2015-01-01 00:00:00.000     1           me          1
1           CS101       2015-01-02 00:00:00.000     1           me          1
1           CS101       2015-01-03 00:00:00.000     1           me          1
1           CS101       2015-01-01 00:00:00.000     2           you         1
1           CS101       2015-01-02 00:00:00.000     2           you         0
1           CS101       2015-01-03 00:00:00.000     2           you         0
2           CS105       2015-01-01 00:00:00.000     1           me          0
2           CS105       2015-01-01 00:00:00.000     2           you         1
```

So you can add some aggregation over that query, to get this:

```
select 
    c.Id as CourseId, c.Name as CourseName,
    s.Id as StudentId, s.Name as StudentName, 
    case 
        when sum(case when a.Id is null then 1 else 0 end) > 0 then 0 
        else 1 
    end as AttendedAllSessions,
    max(a.TakenOn) as LastSessionAttended
from (
    select distinct CourseId, TakenOn [SessionDate] from SessionAttendance 
) cs
join Course c on c.Id=cs.CourseId
cross join Student s
left join SessionAttendance a on 
    a.CourseId=cs.CourseId and a.StudentId=s.Id and a.TakenOn=cs.SessionDate
group by c.Id, c.Name, s.Id, s.Name
```

Which gives you a result like:

```
CourseId    CourseName  StudentId   StudentName AttendedAllSessions LastSessionAttended
1           CS101       1           me          1                   2015-01-03 00:00:00.000
1           CS101       2           you         0                   2015-01-01 00:00:00.000
2           CS105       1           me          0                   NULL
2           CS105       2           you         1                   2015-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e6154/3).

Comment: ah. Course ⨯ Students is what I was missing in my thinking